# Excel macro/formula - replace cell values if value does NOT appear in another column

Tags: excel

I need help.  I have a list of 20 names of certain consultants.  I receive a new sheet daily with many names, and if one of them does not match with any of the 20 consultant names, I need to replace the cell value with "X".

E.g. 
1. Consultant's list contains John and Mary.
2. Daily list contains 5 names: John, Steve, Dean, Mary and Sue.
3. I now want to replace all the cell which does NOT contain John and Mary with X (thus replace cell with names Steve, Dean and Sue with X)

Help will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Please post any formulas or code you've written and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If your 20-name list is in ColumnA and the daily list in ColumnB each starting in Row1 then in Row 1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),"X",B1)
```